# A computer represents information in groups of 32 bits

Tags: computer-science

A computer represents information in groups of 32 bits. How many different integers can be represented in 
(a) binary
(b) BCD
(c) 8-bit ASCII
all using 32 bits?

/*The problem is i have no idea where to begin and how it works. can anyone explain it to me or atleast send me a book so i can read and understand it? */

Comment: google for "binary representation". https://www.bottomupcs.com/chapter01.xhtml seems to be a good start...

Comment: In binary, each setting of bits represents a distinct number. Figure out the number of possible settings. In BCD, each group of four bits can represent at most one decimal digit. Count the number of such groups in 32 bits, then figure out how many values that many digits can have.  In ASCII, each group of eight bits can represent at most one decimal digit. Count the number of such groups in 32 bits, then figure out how many values that many digits can have.

Comment: From a combinatorics perspective, it's permutation with repetition problem. Computer science is filled with combinatorics problems. It's a good elective if it's not a degree requirement.